# MQTT.fx can't connect to AWS IoT (MqttException)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/getting-started-with-amazon-aws-for-iot-projects

**I did the all steps again and again but I can't get rid of MqttException error when click on "Connect" button in MQTT.fx.**

**I download the certificates from AWS IoT and keep them in C:\temp folder. I also checked log tab in MQTT.fx here you can see that below. Do you have any idea about how to solve it?**

Thanks a lot!

> 2020-10-09 10:40:28,043 ERROR --- MqttFX ClientModel             :
> Please verify your Settings (e.g. Broker Address, Broker Port & Client
> ID) and the user credentials!
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: MqttException   at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:715)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> [?:1.8.0_162]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> [?:1.8.0_162]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_162]
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:108)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     ... 7 more Caused by:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:108)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     ... 7 more Caused by:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_162]    at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:108)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     ... 7 more 2020-10-09
> 10:40:28,045  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
> 2020-10-09 10:40:28,046 ERROR --- BrokerConnectService           :
> MqttException

Comment: "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target "  -- it can't find your SSL Certs by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
It was about downloading the wrong certificate. You can find detailed solution here.

After you create a thing in AWS IoT, download all the 3 certificates.

If you want to get the CA certificate which is necessary for MQTT.fx you need to go [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/server-authentication.html?icmpid=docs_iot_console#server-authentication-certs) (you will see this link under the download certificates section in AWS IoT after you create your thing) and click on **RSA 2048 bit key: Amazon Root CA 1** link. New tab will be open.

Copy and paste this certificate to your notepad. Name it Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem and select All File types when you are saving it.

Put all the certificates in one file. I keep them under C:\temp folder.

And finally, this is how my configuration looks like:[MQTT.fx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goOlt.png)

Now MQTT.fx will work hopefully :)